# AngularJs call parent controller function with parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have two controller's and I want to call other parent controller function with parameter when user clicks the button.

**Html**

```
<a ng-click='test('something')'>Click</a>
```

**Controller**

```
controller: function($scope) {
        ..........
   $scope.test= $scope.$parent.parentTest(t);// it fails...

..........}
```

**Parent Controller**

```
$scope.parentTest= function(m) {

   var my=m;

   ...Something...

}
```

If I run function without any parameter, it works.  If I run the function with parameter it doesn't.

I want to call parent function with parameter.

Comment: Formatting and grammar.

Answer (score 4):

The mistake in your code is with this line:

```
//This assigns the RESULT of parentTest() to $scope.test
$scope.test= $scope.$parent.parentTest(t);
```

// Either of the 2 options below will probably work for you.

```
//This assigns the parentTest Function itself to $scope.test
$scope.test= $scope.$parent.parentTest;

//This wraps it safely in case the parentTest function isn't ready when
// this controller initializes
$scope.test= function(t){$scope.$parent.parentTest(t)}; // << Change it to this!
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Console error? What happens?
Is $scope.$parent.parentTest undefined? Is $scope.test called at all?

Answer (score 0):

Check this plunkr, maybe this can help you

```
plunkr
```

[access parentfunction in child controller](http://plnkr.co/edit/zw5WJVhr7OKqACoJhDZw?p=preview)